# Typescript inline object constructor with generics results in too broad type

Tags: typescript

For a project I needed to create a type with two type generics to create single-key objects:

```js
type MyVariant<K extends string, V> = {
    [key in K]: V
}
```

To create objects of this type I've written the following function:

```js
function createVariant<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): MyVariant<K, V>  {
    return {
        [key]: value
    };
}
```

This function uses the same generic types for the input key and value as for the resulting variant. When using the shorthand inline constructor for the resulting object, typescript complains with the following message:
`Type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to type 'MyVariant<K, V>'`

In my understanding the key type `x` shouldn't be of type string but of type `K` as this is the type it was given from the function parameters.
To make typescript accept the return value, the function needs to be modified like so:

```js
function createVariant<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): MyVariant<K, V>  {
    return {
        [key]: value
    } as MyVariant<K, V>;
}
```

In my opinion this is an unnecessary cast as the resulting type already matches the required output type.
Is there a better way to build an object of MyVariant from generics that is accepted by typescript without having to cast the type to the required output?

Comment: You can overload your function. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/NBeobw). TS infers `{ [key]: value }` as `{ [key: string]: value }` because it is the safest assumption he can do about return type. Also, I believe  it is justified to use `as` type assertion in this case. Some times you just need to use assertions due to dynamic nature of JavaScript. Please keep in mind that arguments are mutable

Comment: @captain-yossarian so even tho key is of type K which is accepted as a key ov MyVariant<K, V> I'm able to construct types that are not a valid MyVariant<K, V> and I therefore need to overload the function to express this?

Comment: I think you are allowed to use type assertion as well in this case. If I were you I would use function overloading, bbut in this particular case it just a matter of preference

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for using the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type): you don't need `MyVariant` or the explicit return type for TS to correctly infer all of the information in your question:

```ts
function createVariant <K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value } as Record<K, V>;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQNQymDMKRAHgGlE0APbMAEwGdFGoCwBzAGkRwD4AFAGs0ATwBcicjwBuGADYg0knAEpEAbwBQiROiggUSDYgDaI0QF1JcxWkQBfRBmYAlNBDgp6FHvwDcWg5AA)

> Note: I'm definitely not against explicit return types

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know the `Record` type existed. But still is there a way to avoid having to cast here?

Comment: @JuliusRiegel Not that I can think of at this moment.